# How can I fix apt-get autoremove wanting to uninstall most of my packages?

Tags: 13.04, apt, synaptic

I did change my packages in synaptic from manually installed to Automatically (they were not manually installed but automatically). Now they are marked for Autoremove.

I tested it with `sudo apt-get autoremove` and the result is shown below (a reduced version because its almost all packages). I remember last year I had same issue and solved it via Ubuntu forums but the forum is down and I cannot reach the post! Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

```
sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
  unity-asset-pool unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
  unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-scope-gdrive
  unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote unity-services
  unity-tweak-tool unity-webapps-amazoncloudreader unity-webapps-common
  unity-webapps-facebookmessenger unity-webapps-gmail unity-webapps-googledocs
  unity-webapps-googleplus unity-webapps-launchpad unity-webapps-linkedi
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xul-ext-unity
  xul-ext-webaccounts xul-ext-websites-integration y-ppa-manager yad zenity
  zenity-common zip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1440 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,853 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching aptitude I found this command that did it all

```
sudo aptitude keep-all
```

And that was it!

Answer (score 4):

The crazy "apt-get-autoremoving-everything" automatically happens to me every time I install a second desktop environment and delete the default one.

If I answer Yes he completely destroy my linux.

Anyway answering no is not a real solution since `apt-get` will keep asking you several times to remove those important packages.

But yesterday I found a strange solution.

I run this command: `aptitude autoclean`

and after that i did again `apt-get autoremove` and the whole unsane list of packages was completely gone.

Now my system is stable and clean.....and I avoided a lot of trouble