# Ubuntu 20.04 Apt Asking Me to Autoremove Important Packages

Tags: apt, package-management, xorg, python3

When I run `apt-get update` & `apt-get upgrade`, I'm suggested to remove the below packages. Running `sudo aptitude keep-all`, `aptitude autoclean`, or `apt-get autoremove` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323351/how-can-i-fix-apt-get-autoremove-wanting-to-uninstall-most-of-my-packages?newreg=2161551658f5458a881111dbd1c86091) doesn't work. I don't remember what I changed to make Ubuntu to suggest deleting all these packages.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils apg apport-symptoms apturl-common
  avahi-utils cups-pk-helper cups-server-common gir1.2-goa-1.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-snapd-1 gnome-control-center-faces hplip-data
  ippusbxd libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
  libauthen-sasl-perl libcolord-gtk1 libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl
  libglu1-mesa libgsound0 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libhpmud0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl
  libhttp-negotiate-perl libimagequant0 libio-socket-ssl-perl liblua5.2-0
  libmailtools-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libsane-hpaio libtie-ixhash-perl libtry-tiny-perl
  libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwww-robotrules-perl libxatracker2
  libxml-xpathengine-perl libxss1 libxvmc1 mobile-broadband-provider-info
  network-manager-gnome perl-openssl-defaults printer-driver-postscript-hp
  python3-cups python3-dateutil python3-debconf python3-distro-info
  python3-distupgrade python3-entrypoints python3-keyring python3-lazr.uri
  python3-olefile python3-pil python3-problem-report python3-protobuf
  python3-pymacaroons python3-renderpm python3-reportlab
  python3-reportlab-accel python3-rfc3339 python3-secretstorage
  python3-simplejson python3-software-properties python3-systemd python3-tz
  python3-update-manager python3-wadllib rygel unattended-upgrades
  whoopsie-preferences x11-apps x11-session-utils xbitmaps xfonts-scalable
  xinit xinput xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Comment: This typically happens when you remove/ uninstall something vitally important for the OS, such as python. Please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1262723/edit) and add which packages you uninstalled recently. Try installing them one at a time and verify it solves the problem.

Comment: Looks like you (perhaps unintentionally) removed `ubuntu-desktop` or a similar desktop metapackage.

Comment: Reinstalling ubuntu-dekstop resolved this. :)